# Book involving two siblings and a magic sword called Excalibur

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I'm pretty sure it involves two siblings fighting crime whose catchphrase is "let's blow this popsicle stand" (or "...soda stand"). There's also а magic sword called Excalibur, I think.

I read it around seven years ago and it should be classified as а young adult book.

Comment: Hi Samuel! What's "a LONG time ago"? Please read [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) on how to write good identification questions, and add as much info as you can. Welcome to Sci-Fi & Fantasy!

Comment: The Excalibur Knights Saga Omnibus? Mention of popsicle stands and excalibur.

Comment: Thirteen? https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Thirteen/X4NCDwAAQBAJ?hl=en

Comment: The "pop stand" (or "soda stand") versions of the expression are older.  The "popsicle stand" form was most likely created by Robin Williams (originally as an ad lib) for *Mork and Mindy* (1978).